# delphi read realtime mobile gps status

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

in android i have to get real time status of mobile phone GPS.so i added a listener to get status with time and location distance of 0
but after a while(5to30 minutes) of working the app crashes and closed.
how can i debug and fix the issue?

```
  if not runTheGpsListener then
  begin
  runTheGpsListener := true;
        if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
        begin
          LocationManagerService := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
          if not Assigned(locationListener) then
            locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
          FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER, 5,1, locationListener, TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);

        end;

  end;
```

and use listener like this

```
procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
  systemCoreTime := StrToInt64( Copy(location.getTime.ToString, 1 , location.getTime.ToString.Length-3) );

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
                procedure
                begin
                   formmain.Memo1.Text := systemCoreTime.ToString;
                end);
end;
```

update1:

i added a boolean variable to run listener one time

also added `Synchronize` for updates,but nothing changed

but crashed again

this is run time log

```
09-09 11:28:05.813 13766 13766 F DEBUG   :     #20 pc 006c30fb  /data/app/com.zafar.handset-1/lib/arm/libhandset.so
09-09 11:28:05.813 13766 13766 F DEBUG   :     #21 pc 00331be3  /data/app/com.zafar.handset-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x327000)
09-09 11:28:08.679   640   640 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 13534
09-09 11:28:08.682   816   839 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
09-09 11:28:08.691   816 13771 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity
09-09 11:28:09.345   816   832 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{e947491 u0 com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity t42 f}
09-09 11:28:09.414   685   685 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/13534/oom_score_adj; errno=22
09-09 11:28:09.515   687   711 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x333 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:09.565   816   832 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8fa6a300, tid 832
09-09 11:28:09.595   687   687 E EGL_emulation: tid 687: eglCreateSyncKHR(1451): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-09 11:28:09.658   816   879 D GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 4
09-09 11:28:09.687   816   892 W InputDispatcher: channel 'b1c7f3d com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0xd
09-09 11:28:09.687   816   892 E InputDispatcher: channel 'b1c7f3d com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-09 11:28:09.688   816   892 W InputDispatcher: channel '77ef4fb com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
09-09 11:28:09.688   816   892 E InputDispatcher: channel '77ef4fb com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-09 11:28:09.711   816   842 W art     : Long monitor contention with owner ActivityManager (832) at android.graphics.Bitmap com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.screenshotApplicationsInner(android.os.IBinder, int, int, int, boolean, float, android.graphics.Bitmap$Config)(WindowManagerService.java:6252) waiters=0 in void com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) for 223ms
09-09 11:28:09.713   691   691 I Zygote  : Process 13534 exited due to signal (6)
09-09 11:28:09.733   816   833 W art     : Long monitor contention with owner ActivityManager (832) at android.graphics.Bitmap com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.screenshotApplicationsInner(android.os.IBinder, int, int, int, boolean, float, android.graphics.Bitmap$Config)(WindowManagerService.java:6252) waiters=1 in int com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow(com.android.server.wm.Session, android.view.IWindow, int, android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams, int, int, int, int, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.content.res.Configuration, android.view.Surface) for 216ms
09-09 11:28:09.795   816  3622 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{77ef4fb u0 com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
09-09 11:28:09.795   816  3622 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '77ef4fb com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)'
09-09 11:28:09.810   816  3376 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-09 11:28:09.811   816  3376 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-09 11:28:09.813   687   711 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:09.815   816   828 W art     : Long monitor contention with owner ActivityManager (832) at android.graphics.Bitmap com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.screenshotApplicationsInner(android.os.IBinder, int, int, int, boolean, float, android.graphics.Bitmap$Config)(WindowManagerService.java:6252) waiters=4 in void com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied() for 150ms
09-09 11:28:09.815   816   828 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{b1c7f3d u0 com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
09-09 11:28:09.816   816   828 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b1c7f3d com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)'
09-09 11:28:09.818   816   828 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.zafar.handset/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1780 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack>
09-09 11:28:09.833   687   711 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:09.834   687   711 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:09.886   816   832 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
09-09 11:28:10.026   816   829 W art     : Long monitor contention with owner ActivityManager (832) at void com.android.server.am.ActivityStack$ActivityStackHandler.handleMessage(android.os.Message)(ActivityStack.java:371) waiters=0 in void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient.binderDied() for 355ms
09-09 11:28:10.027   816   829 I ActivityManager: Process com.zafar.handset (pid 13534) has died
09-09 11:28:10.177   816   833 I Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-09 11:28:10.340  1020  1020 W asset   : Asset path /data/app/com.zafar.handset-2/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
09-09 11:28:10.368   687   713 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:10.376   687   711 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:10.377  1020  1020 W PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.zafar.handset
09-09 11:28:10.387   687   711 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:10.492   687   749 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:10.539   816   826 I art     : Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10744(957KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(1944KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 15MB/19MB, paused 33.689ms total 760.433ms
09-09 11:28:10.827   687   711 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:10.852  1020  1042 I art     : Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 39803(1358KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 32% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 97.535ms total 411.516ms
09-09 11:28:10.943   687   713 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
09-09 11:28:10.995  1377  1437 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a boolean flag so that your FormShow code only executes the fisr time the event fires?

Comment: I sounds like a memory leak problem. Use FastMM4 to catch memory leak problems.

Comment: Is there only one instance of the TFormMain class or are several instanes created?

Comment: One possible problem is that the event handler can be executed in a different thread than the UI thread. Use `TThread.Synchronize()` to wrap the code that sets the Memo text in the form.

Comment: i didn't knew formshow trigger different times,is it help if i move the code to oncreate event!?

Comment: you must use Grijjy.ErrorReporting (https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/02/21/build-your-own-error-reporter-part-2-android/) to know exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you haven't declared your `LocationListener` correctly.

Here are snippets that show you how to do some of it:

```
type
  TLocationListener = class;
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    ToolBarLabel: TLabel;
```

...

```
 private
    { Private declarations }
    FLocationManager : JLocationManager;
    locationListener : TLocationListener;
```

...

```
  TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
  private
    [weak]
    FParent : TfrmMain;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent : TfrmMain);
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
  end;
```

...

```
procedure TfrmMain.StartLocation;
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
  location : JLocation;
begin

  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    LocationManagerService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
      locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
  end;

  FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER,
      Round(MINREPFREQ * 1000), 30, locationListener,
        TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);

end;
```